# How to prevent carriage return/enter on all form elements except textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I recently took over an existing project and ran into problems with textareas and carriage return not working. I found the code below after some digging:

```
$(window).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

So, I take it this is to prevent form elements from submitting the form when a visitor/user press carriage return.

Any idea how I can keep the functionality of the above code-snippet, and still allow carriage returns in textareas?

Comment: did you entered the code with phpMyAdmin or so? Then i bet its a decoding problem. Try either utf8_decode() or encode() and try it with data your script added to the DB

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but phpMyAdmin is not part of the project in any way. I know the view-template is using encoding utf-8, but not sure if I need to add any encoding options to the json or database framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to close this question, I found a solution for the followup-question: How to prevent return/enter on all form elements except textareas.

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && e.target.nodeName != "TEXTAREA") {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```